# How to show the profile image/photo of a user in Teams tab?

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

#### Problem

In our Teams app tab we want to show the profile image/photo of the current user.

#### Things we tried

- The user is authenticated with [Single Sign-on for tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) and we store some user information to track some progress in our app. It is not possible to fetch the profile image from the Microsoft Graph API with the token from the *Single Sign-On* process — the `User.Read` permission is missing.
- The user profile image does not seem to be available in the Teams context from the Microsoft Teams Javascript SDK.
- In SharePoint it is possible to show the profile image of the current user with a special URL: `https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?size=L&accountname=<upn>`. This fails in Teams with an "no access" redirect if the user has not logged in into SharePoint.

#### Seemingly possible solutions

- Extra authentication step to get the `User.Read` permission; not ideal, nobody is gonna press a extra button just so we can show a profile image.
- Convince the *Single Sign-on for tabs* process to include `User.Read`; Adding the permission in all kinds of configuration did not change anything in the resulting token.
- Use a custom OAuth2 flow, according to [this blog post](https://blog.soft-cor.com/getting-an-id_token-from-the-azure-bot-service-when-leveraging-bot-authentication-in-microsoft-teams/) it is possible to setup in the *Single Sign-On for **bots*** process. The Teams SDK does not seem to have the same possiblility.
- Somehow make sure a user is authenticated in SharePoint so we can use the magic profile image URL; does not seem very likely.

Is there a solution workaround and/or something that we did not try yet for this problem?

Comment: Unrelated comment, but I love the avatar!

Comment: You need to call Graph API to get the Profile Image and then show it in tab.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#examples

Comment: Fetching the profile image from the Microsoft Graph API needs an additional permission (`User.Read`), I'd like to prevent that. It means a user has to give permission twice to use the app, once to be able to login and the second one is _only_ for the profile image.

Comment: as per my understanding user.read is bydefault added permission when you register the Bot.so you need to call the Graph API get the Profile Image.

Comment: This is not the case, when using the Single Sign-On process for either the bots or the tabs the `User.Read` permission is not available in the token that you get (through the `on_behalf_of` flow).

Comment: you need token exchange from server side to get the user.read permission if you use  on_behalf_of  flow.here is sample:-
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/app-complete-auth/csharp/AppCompleteAuth/Pages/tab.cshtml

Comment: The `on_behalf_of` does not provide `User.Read` permissions, you need additional consent from the user. If it's not possible to get the profile image without additional consent, then that's also an answer — we just like to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to modify what the standard SSO does, unfortunately.

The easiest way to deal with this is to use the Microsoft Graph Toolkit, specifically the [Person component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/components/person). It's exactly built for this kind of scenario, and you have the user's AadObjectId from the Teams context.

It does require an Azure Application, but I think you can use the same app. It -will- prompt the user, by default, with a consent popup, but you can get around this, as always, with an admin consenting on behalf of the user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately this is not going to solve our problem, the prompt that is needed for this to work is a deal-breaker — at the very least, we want to explore options without it first. The admin consent is something that exists in future steps in our product. We want to provide an as complete as possible preview of our product for "regular" users, before the whole organization signs up with admin consent. Thanks again!